# Последовательная многопоточная обработка данных QThread Python

Tags: многопоточность, python-2.x, pyqt4

Здравствуйте. Есть плагин для QGIS, в котором я создаю 4 потока QThread: в отдельном от GUI потоке создается маска облачности для космоснимка, потом в двух новых потоках производится параллельная предварительная обработка 4 и 5 канала набора данных спутника Landsat и в заключительном потоке производится расчет показателя NDVI. Все эти 3 этапа реализованы в виде методов класса work. Каждый раз экземпляр класса work помещается в отдельный поток QThread, а поток по сигналу старт(started) запускает нужный метод (этап обработки). 
В конце первых 2-х методов выпускается сигнал для создания нового потока, в котором будет выполняться следующий метод.

Сейчас я дорабатываю свою прогу-костыль, чтобы она могла обрабатывать несколько космоснимков и рассчитывать NDVI для них. Для этого я выпускаю сигнал 'next' после заключительного этапа (расчет NDVI), чтобы заново начать эту процедуру. Проблема заключается в том, что после 3-х этапов для первого снимка и создании маски облачности для второго снимка (первый этап) программа далее ничего не вычисляет, но и ошибок в отладчике нет. Скорее всего проблема кроется в строке self.cloudmask_ended.emit(), которая по каким-то причинам не приводит к переходу к следующему этапу. Приведу отрывок кода ниже, буду очень благодарен за помощь.

P.S. Для ясности кода: метод thread_start вызывается по сигналу после нажатия кнопки "Run" (т.е. кнопки для запуска расчетов). cloudmask_ended, processing_ended - это сигналы обозначающие конец расчетов для первого и второго метода (этапа) соответственно. Сигнал sendGlobalVar и метод receive_data предназначены для передачи в класс work абсолютного пути к снимку и его названия.

```
def thread_start(self):
    self.thread_cloud = QThread(self.dlg)
    self.work_cloud = work(0)      
    self.work_cloud.moveToThread(self.thread_cloud) 
    self.thread_cloud.started.connect(self.work_cloud.cloudmask_)
    self.work_cloud.cloudmask_ended.connect(self.cloudmask_end)
    self.work_cloud.finished.connect(self.thread_cloud.quit, Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection)
    self.work_cloud.finished.connect(self.work_cloud.deleteLater, Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection)
    self.thread_cloud.finished.connect(self.thread_cloud.deleteLater, Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection)
    self.work_cloud.sendGlobalVar.connect(self.work_cloud.receive_data, Qt.DirectConnection)
    self.work_cloud.sendGlobalVar.emit(self.paths_lst[self.ind][0],self.paths_lst[self.ind][1])
    self.thread_cloud.start() 

#Метод calculate_end запускает в отдельном потоке расчет NDVI сразу после предварительной обработки космоснимков    
def calculate_end(self, ended):
    if ended == 3:
        self.B4_finished = True
    elif ended == 4:
        self.B5_finished = True
    if self.B4_finished and self.B5_finished:
        self.thread = QThread(self.dlg)
        self.work = work(0)
        self.work.moveToThread(self.thread) 

        self.thread.started.connect(self.work.NDVI_calculation)
        self.work.show.connect(self.showNDVI)
        self.work.finished.connect(self.work.deleteLater, Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater, Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection)
        self.work.sendGlobalVar.connect(self.work.receive_data, Qt.DirectConnection)
        self.work.next.connect(self.go_next, Qt.DirectConnection)

        self.work.sendGlobalVar.emit(self.paths_lst[self.ind][0],self.paths_lst[self.ind][1])
        self.thread.start()

def go_next(self):
    if self.ind+1 < len(self.paths_lst):
        self.ind += 1
        self.thread_start()

def cloudmask_end(self):
    self.B4_finished = False
    self.B5_finished = False

    self.thread_B4 = QThread(self.dlg)
    self.work_B4 = work(3)
    self.work_B4.moveToThread(self.thread_B4)        

    self.thread_B4.started.connect(self.work_B4.processing_)
    self.work_B4.processing_ended.connect(self.calculate_end)
    self.work_B4.finished.connect(self.thread_B4.quit, Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection)
    self.work_B4.finished.connect(self.work_B4.deleteLater, Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection)
    self.thread_B4.finished.connect(self.thread_B4.deleteLater, Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection)
    self.work_B4.sendGlobalVar.connect(self.work_B4.receive_data, Qt.DirectConnection)

    self.thread_B5 = QThread(self.dlg)
    self.work_B5 = work(4)
    self.work_B5.moveToThread(self.thread_B5)        

    self.thread_B5.started.connect(self.work_B5.processing_)
    self.work_B5.processing_ended.connect(self.calculate_end)
    self.work_B5.finished.connect(self.thread_B5.quit, Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection)
    self.work_B5.finished.connect(self.work_B5.deleteLater, Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection)
    self.thread_B5.finished.connect(self.thread_B5.deleteLater, Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection)
    self.work_B5.sendGlobalVar.connect(self.work_B5.receive_data, Qt.DirectConnection)

    self.work_B4.sendGlobalVar.emit(self.paths_lst[self.ind][0],self.paths_lst[self.ind][1])
    self.work_B5.sendGlobalVar.emit(self.paths_lst[self.ind][0],self.paths_lst[self.ind][1])
    self.thread_B4.start() 
    self.thread_B5.start()

class work(QObject):
  #Создание сигналов
  finished = pyqtSignal()
  sendGlobalVar = pyqtSignal(str, str)
  cloudmask_ended = pyqtSignal()
  processing_ended = pyqtSignal(int)
  show = pyqtSignal()
  next = pyqtSignal()

  def __init__(self, band_num):        
    super(work, self).__init__()
    self.band = band_num

#Метод создает маску облачности, устанавливает вычислительный регион
  @pyqtSlot()
  def cloudmask_(self):
     ........
     self.cloudmask_ended.emit()
     self.finished.emit()

#Метод импортирует космоснимки в набор grass, производит радиометрическую калибровку и атмосферную коррекцию
  @pyqtSlot()
  def processing_(self):
      .........
      self.processing_ended.emit(self.band)
      self.finished.emit() 

#Метод для получения переменной fileName из класса NDVIcalculation и значения lineEdit
  def receive_data(self, str1, str2):
     global fileName
     global path
     fileName = str1
     path = str2

#Расчет NDVI
  @pyqtSlot()
  def NDVI_calculation(self):
     ................
     self.next.emit()
     self.finished.emit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, поменяв местами вызовы сигналов, т.е. переместив сигнал finished выше. Также убрал тип соединения Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection и в каждом этапе в самом начале блокировал поток связанный с предыдущим этапом методом wait класса QThread, пока тот не удалится. В итоге программа работает, но в ходе работы программы может появиться ошибка в QGIS, которая просто указывает на файл дампа памяти с непонятной ошибкой, вследствие чего QGIS придется перезапустить, но результат работы программы будет получен.